# extending scripting integration to an existing lib

Tags: python, scripting, swig

I found swig can generate script wrapper for various scripting languages.
I've a 3rd party static library, a header file and a lib.

How can I use swig so that I can call functions from that library from a scripting language, say python?

Thanks

Comment: What is your specific question? Did you read the swig documentation first?

Comment: The tutorial walkthrough has C implementation source as well. My question is can we do such integration if we only have header and static lib file without implementation source. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the [swig](http://swig.org/) documentation. It walks through examples of how to do exactly this.